# How to override parent @MappedSuperclass @column attributes in child entity extending parent while inserting child entity

Tags: entity, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, mappedsuperclass

I have two classes A & B, B extends A and A is @MappedSuperclass as it is extended by other entities as well for some common fields.

**Class A**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class A implements Serializable { 

@Column(name="TYPE_ID")
private String type;

@Column(name="FEATURE_CODE")
private String featureCode;

}
```

**Class B**

```
public class B extends A implements Serializable { 

@Column(name="ID")
private String id;

@Column(name="GROUP")
private String group;

}
```

Now the problem is while I'm trying to persist class B it takes **TYPE_ID** and **FEATURE_CODE** into the INSERT query and the target database table **TABLE B** doesn't have the column **FEATURE_CODE** which results in exception.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to ignore the FEATURE_CODE field while persisting the child entity B?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

@MappedSuperclass needs a constructor and its get and set. and your class, B,..

must have the columns of A in the database, if you do it with hibernate you should create them automatically, but if you do it manually, you must create the columns of A in the table of B